# Program Works only debug mode but not in normal exe (using c lion)?

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures, clion, infix-operator

SO i created a program that converts from infix to post fix and prefix which works just fine. The thing is that I am using C-LION which has its own debugger that allows me to go step by step and I do that the program works fine and outputs the expected results BUT then when I run it normally IT DOES NOT  WORK AND GIVES ME A "main.c not working " ERROR.

This the main function that has the menu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

char*infixToPostfix(char *infinx);
char* postixToinfix(char *infinx);
char* postixToprefix(char *infinx);
char* prefixToinfix(char *infinx);
char* prefixTopostfix(char *infinx);
char* infixToPrefix(char *infinx);
char*evaluate(char *infinx );
int exp_det(char*exp);
typedef struct node
{
    char *op;
    int  p;
    struct node *next; /* Pointer to the next node. Notice that the
    existence of the structure tag enables us to declare its type. */
} node;
node *head=NULL; /* Global pointer that always points to the head of the
    stack. */
int precedence(char symbol);
void add_stack(const node *p);
void pop(void);
int main(void)
{
    char postfix[100];
    int choice;
    //converting from ininfinx to postfix
    printf("\t\t***** Conversion Calculator 1.0 ******\t\t\n");
    printf("\t\t1.Convert\n\t\t2.Evaluate\n\t\t3.Exit\nEnter Choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    //switch (choice){
        if (choice==1) {
            printf("\n\t\t1.Input from File\n\t\t2.standered  input\nEnter Choice :");
            int ch2;
            scanf("%d", &ch2);
            switch (ch2) {
                case 1:
                    printf("FILE MANGAMENT STILL NOT DONE !!!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Enter Expression : ");
                    char line[256];


                    scanf(" %[^\n]s", postfix);
                    char in2[100] = {'\0'};
                    char in3[100] = {'\0'};
                    char *conv;
                    char *conv2;

                    strcpy(in2, postfix);
                    strcpy(in3, postfix);
                    int exp = exp_det(in2);

                    if (exp == 1) {
                        printf("\nThis is a Prefix expression do you want to\n\t\t1.Infix\n\t\t2.Postfix\n\t\t3.Both\nEnter Choice :");
                        int ch3;
                        scanf("%d", &ch3);
                        switch (ch3) {
                            case 1:
                                conv = prefixToinfix(in3);
                                printf("Expression in Infix form: %s \n", in3);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                conv = prefixTopostfix(in3);
                                printf("Expression in Postfix form: %s \n", in3);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                conv = prefixToinfix(in3);
                                conv2 = prefixTopostfix(postfix);
                                printf("Expression in Infix form: %s \n", conv);
                                printf("Expression in Postfix form: %s \n", conv2);
                                break;
                            default:
                                printf("ERROROR WHEN EXPRESSION IN PREFIX ");

                                break;
                        }
                    } else if (exp == 2) {
                        printf("\nThis is a Infix expression do you want to\n\t\t1.Prefix\n\t\t2.Postfix\n\t\t3.Both\nEnter Choice :");
                        int ch3;
                        scanf("%d", &ch3);
                        switch (ch3) {
                            case 1:
                                printf("Expression in prefix form: %s \n", infixToPrefix(postfix));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                printf("Expression in Postfix form: %s \n", infixToPostfix(postfix));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                printf("Expression in prefix form: %s \n", infixToPrefix(postfix));
                                printf("Expression in Postfix form: %s \n", infixToPostfix(postfix));
                                break;
                            default:
                                printf("ERROROR R");

                                break;
                        }
                    } else if (exp == 3) {
                        printf("This is a Postfix expression do you want to\n\t\t1.Infix\n\t\t2.Prefix\n\t\t3.Both\nEnter Choice :");
                        int ch3;
                        scanf("%d", &ch3);
                        switch (ch3) {
                            case 1:
                                printf("Expression in Infix form: %s \n", postixToinfix(postfix));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                printf("Expression in prefix form: %s \n", postixToprefix(postfix));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                printf("Expression in Infix form: %s \n", postixToinfix(postfix));
                                printf("Expression in Prefix form: %s \n", postixToprefix(postfix));
                                break;
                            default:
                                printf("ERROR... 3:(\n");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;//for the switch with ch2 case 1
                default:
                    printf("ERROR... 2:(\n");
                    break;
            }
            //break;
        }if(choice==2) {
        printf("Enter Expression : ");

        scanf(" %[^\n]s", postfix);
        char in2[100] = {'\0'};
        char in3[100] = {'\0'};
        char *conv;
        char *conv2;

        strcpy(in2, postfix);
        conv = evaluate(in2);
        printf("\nExpression evaluated = %s \n", conv);
        //break;
    }if(choice==3) {
        printf("BYE...... :D\n");


    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

OK Now after much trials I am starting to think that the problem is in the conversion itself. This is one of the functions i am using for me it looks fine. If anyone has another opinion help is greatly appropriated.

```
char* infixToPostfix(char *infinx){
char* token;

char * infinx1=malloc(sizeof(infinx)+1);

infinx1=strcpy(infinx1,infinx);

token = strtok(infinx1," ");

char* res;
res=malloc(sizeof(infinx)+sizeof(head->op)*strlen(infinx));

strcpy(res," ");

if(*token=='\n' ){token=strtok(NULL," ");}

while( token != NULL ) {

    node n;
    n.op=token;
    n.p=precedence(*token);
    if(isalpha(*token) || isdigit(*token)){
        // strcat(result,infinx[i]);
        //printf("%c",infinx[i]);

        res=strcat(res,token);
        res=strcat(res," ");
    }
        //case when encounter a left paranthessisis
    else if(*token=='(' || *token==')'){
        if (*token=='('){
            add_stack(&n);
        }else if(*token==')') {

            while (*head->op != '(') {
                // strcat(result, n.op);
                //printf("%c",(char)head->op);
                res=strcat(res,head->op);
                res=strcat(res," ");
                pop();
            }
            pop();
        }
    }
        //if head if null meaning the stack is empty or if the presendance of the head is less thatn or equal to new character
    else if(head==NULL || head->p < n.p ){
        if (head->p == n.p){}
        add_stack(&n);
    }
        //in case the head has higher presendance he we pop and print untill we reach the same presedance
    else  {
        while( head!=NULL && head->p >= n.p){
            //strcat(result,n.op);
            //printf("%c",(char)head->op);
            res=strcat(res,head->op);
            res=strcat(res," ");
            pop();
        }
        add_stack(&n);
    }
    token=strtok(NULL," ");
}
while(head!=NULL){
    //strcat(result,head->op);
    //printf("%c",(char)head->op);
    res=strcat(res,head->op);
    res=strcat(res," ");
    pop();
}
return res;
```

}

Comment: How are you running it "normally"? It sounds like you're trying to run main.c not the executable

Comment: normally you mean by pressing run icon in IDE or starting builded output file through your directory or terminal?

Comment: Yeah I mean  running it using the run icon in the IDE

Comment: You have a very odd way of declaring variables in the nested case statements. My compiler cannot figure out if they are used or not. Or if they are declared *when* they are used. Like if `ch2 == 2` some variables are declared, and if `exp == 1` and `ch3 == 3` they might get used? And you have several `ch3` variables to confuse us totally. I'm not surprised if your compiler gets confused too.

Comment: So your saying I should define them outside the switch statement ? @BoPersson

Comment: `"main.c not working "` - perhaps main.c is on the strike? or holiday?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 perhaps you should take a break as well from the Internet

Comment: Working in debug, but not without, is a classic symptom of UB.  Uninitialized vars, out-of-bounds array access, missing NUL-terminators, those kind of things.

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", postfix);`  this will not work.  Because the input will not have a 'literal' `s` as the first character in the next line of input AND the newline is not yet consumed.   Also, notice that `%[...]` will not limit the number of characters entered, so can overflow the input buffer.  Always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  One less because this input format specifier always appends a NUL byte to the buffer.  Suggest using: `scanf(" %99[^\n]", postfix);`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `system("PAUSE");`  This shell command 'PAUSE' is not portable, as it is not implemented on the *unx OSs.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.  3) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100 (and the coded values for the menu responses)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `enum` statements for the menu response values  Suggest using a `#define` statement for the 100

Comment: it is a good programming practice to separate the struct definition from any `typedef` for that struct.  It is quite messy to declare the global data in the middle of the lit of prototypes,  Suggest the struct definition, the typedef for that struct and the declaration of an instance of the struct be before the list of prototypes

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: insert appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: regarding: `system("PAUSE");`:  This can be much more portably written as:  `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Comment: Your `malloc(sizeof(infinx)+sizeof(head->op)*strlen(infinx));` line is strange. I don't get why you do the first `sizeof`, the second is correct, but I think that's more a happy accident. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to your question **"So your saying I should define them outside the switch statement?"** which reflects correctly one of the problems in your code.

Either: You can define them outside to solve the issue.

Or: You can introduce appropriate block scopes to solve the issue.

As the former is trivial, I will elaborate the latter:

### 1. Scope and Variables

The life-time of a local variable starts at its declaration and ends with surrounding block scope.

Example:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0; /* a starts to live. */
  { /* new scope */
    int b = 1; /* b starts to live */
    int a = 2; /* a new a starts to live. (The one of out scope is eclipsed.) */
  } /* Life of b and the inner a ends. The eclipsed outer a becomes visible again. */
  return 0;
}
```

### 2. `switch` and `case`

In opposition to other languages (like e.g. Pascal), the C `switch` statement is rather a "`goto` depending on expression" than a multiway branching with multiple alternatives. (This does not mean that `switch` *cannot* be used for the latter but it *can* be used different as well.) (Please, see [Wikipedia: Control Flow: 5.2 Case and switch statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Case_and_switch_statements) to understand what I mean.)

Imagine the following (wrong) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  goto L1;
  int i = 1;
L1:
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

The `goto L1;` skips the declaration of `int i = 1;` but after `L1:` it is used in `printf()` – ouch!

Out of curiosity, I tried it in [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/WbllUC) – it compiled and ran without complaints. Output was `0` although it could have been as well `1`, `2`, or any other number which can be stored as `int`.

This is the same in the following (wrong) sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int cond = 2;
  switch (cond) {
    case 1:
      printf("case 1\n");
      int i = 1;
    case 2:
      printf("case 2: %d\n", i);
  } /* Here ends the life-time of i */
  return 0;
}
```

Again, I compiled and tested in [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/JdA2Hx).
Output was `case 2: 0`. Ouch again!

### Solution

To mimic multi-branching correctly, the following things are necessary:

1. End each `case` with a `break`.
2. Start a scope after each colon of a `case`.
3. End this scope before the corresponding `break`.

Example again:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int cond = 2;
  switch (cond) {
    case 0: case 1: { /* <- start scope */
      int i = 1;
      printf("case 1: %d\n", i);
    } break; /* <- end scope and jump to end of switch */
    case 2:
      printf("case 2: %d\n", i); /* i is recognized as unknown identifier */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled in [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/kccb4i):

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:12:34: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
           printf("case 2: %d\n", i); /* i is recognized as unknown identifier */
                                  ^
```

As the scope of variable `i` is limited to the range from the possible entrance (`case 0: case 1:`) until the possible exit (`break`) – no other possible code path may access it.